# Create an EditText on a Bitmap - Android programming

Tags: android, bitmap, android-edittext

I wonder if it is possible to have an EditText on a Bitmap, in Android. I want that the user shall be able to enter some text in the EditText, which shall appear at the bottom of the screen, but also be able to see and click on the Bitmap. I saw similar questions, but I couldn't find any answer to them. Anyone solved this issue? Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by putting both the `ImageView` (for your `Bitmap`) and the `EditText` into a `RelativeLayout`. The `EditText` should be placed on top. Use the `EditText` "visibility" property to hide it when not desired.

**Example**:

```
editText.setVisibility(EditText.INVISIBLE);
```

If you need to display the `EditText` alternatively at the bottom of the screen or within the `Bitmap`, then you should use two `EditText` objects and switch between them as necessary.

If you need to move the `EditText` that is overlaid on the `ImageView/Bitmap`, then use `LayoutParameters` to move the `EditText`.

Comment: Thanks! I used your advise and it worked well. I have used however FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout.